# How to worksheetfunction.Trim a very long string in VBA?

Tags: string, vba, excel

I know it's weird asking this question. But what I am facing is not less weird.

I have some long strings (About 1000 chars or more -- Update: Sorry, not 1000, but around 39000, my bad) . They contain spaces which I want to trim.

Acting on common sense, I used `Worksheetfunction.Trim` to do the job. It worked with some short string (around 500 chars). However, as the string got larger (over 39000 chars), it kept returning the error `'1004' - unable to get trim property of the worksheetfunction class`

In doubt, I performed some tests with long string in a worksheet. I entered a dummy string like "aaaaaabbbbbbcccc..." in a cell and `=TRIM(string)` it in another cell. It works.
How does it work in worksheet but not in VBA. I am kinda confused.

To do the work, I made my own TRIM function as a workaround. But I still want to know what was happening with `worksheetfunction.Trim`. What is the limit of `Worksheetfunction.Trim` ?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Here is my code:

I use the following functions:
`get_address(wks as worksheet) as string` : to get address of all ranges containing data in form of constant and formula.

`EXNUM(TextIn as string, optional separator as string = " ") as string` : to remove all non-numeric character from a string

First I will get the range address with `get_address` then `EXNUM` the address.
Then I will run `worksheetfunction.trim` on EXNUM's result

```
Function get_address(wks As Worksheet) As String

    '***Find the range***
    Dim rs1 As range, rs2 As range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rs1 = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           Set rs1 = Nothing
        End If

    Set rs2 = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set rs2 = Nothing
        End If

    '***Extract range address***
    Dim ad1 As String, ad2 As String
    Dim result As String

    ad1 = area_address(rs1)
    ad2 = area_address(rs2)

    result = ad1 & "," & ad2

    If Right(result, 1) = "," Then
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If

    get_address = result
End Function



Function EXNUM(TextIn As String, _
                Optional separator As String = " ") As String

Dim x As Double
Dim result As String

    For x = 1 To Len(TextIn)
            If Not IsNumeric(Mid(TextIn, x, 1)) Then
                result = result + separator
            Else
                result = result + Mid(TextIn, x, 1)
            End If
    Next x

    If Len(result) >= 1 And Right(result, 1) = separator Then
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If

EXNUM = result
End Function

'**********Supporting function only************

Public Function area_address(r As range) As String

    Dim x As Double
    Dim result As String

    For x = 1 To r.Areas.count

    result = result + r.Areas.Item(x).address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False) + ","
    Next x

    If Right(result, 1) = "," Then
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If
    'Debug.Print r.Areas.count
    area_address = result
End Function
```

Here is the screen shot of the error and len of the string

[image]

UPDATE: 
 @brettdj: here is what I am working on. It is a fairly simple idea. I want to create a function called DetectSizeX.
I input a worksheet or a range, the DetectSizeX will return address of a smaller range contain all the data in the larger range/worksheet.

For instance: `DetectSizeX(Activesheet)` ==> return `"A3:T3568"`
My function works like this:

**Step 1**: detect the fragmented range contain all the data by using:

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

**Step 2**: get address of all the fragmented range in the big range gotten from above. join all the address into one string. Call it `r_address`.

`r_address` looks like "A1, B33:C88, T6:Z90, K7:Z100..."
**Step 3**: get the top-left and bot-right cells' address

The largest number in `r_address` string represents the last row.
The smallest number in `r_address` string represents the first row.

Also

The "largest" col name (like A, B, AA, AZ) in `r_address` represent the last column
The "smallest" col name in `r_address` represent the first column.

`Concatenate(smallest col name, smallest number)`
and
`Concatenate(largest col name, largest number)`

give me the address of two cells which I can use to determine the range as the result of DetectSizeX

Here is my full code for anyone who is interested in, it is pretty long:
Any suggestion and improvement is welcomed and appreciated :)

```
'====================================
'**********Detectsize V6*************
'====================================

Public Function DetectSizeX_v6(WorkSheetIn As Worksheet, Optional r_ad As String = vbNullString) As String
'**Note: if DetectSizeX_v5 return a string "0", it means an error, should skip that worksheet
    Dim address As String
    Dim top_left As String
    Dim bot_right As String

    Dim max_row As Double
    Dim min_num As Double
    Dim max_col As String
    Dim min_col As String

    If r_ad = vbNullString Then
        address = get_address(WorkSheetIn)
    Else
        address = get_address_range(WorkSheetIn, r_ad)
    End If

    If Len(address) > 0 Then
        max_row = get_row(address, True)
        min_num = get_row(address, False)

        max_col = get_col_name(address, True)
        min_col = get_col_name(address, False)

        top_left = min_col & min_num
        bot_right = max_col & max_row

        DetectSizeX_v6 = top_left & ":" & bot_right
    Else
        DetectSizeX_v6 = "0"
    End If
End Function

'*************GET_ADDRESS HERE*********************

Public Function get_address(wks As Worksheet) As String

    '***Find the range***
    Dim rs1 As range, rs2 As range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rs1 = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           Set rs1 = Nothing
        End If

    Set rs2 = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set rs2 = Nothing
        End If

    '***Extract range address***
    Dim ad1 As String, ad2 As String
    Dim result As String

    ad1 = area_address(rs1)
    ad2 = area_address(rs2)

    result = ad1 & "," & ad2

    If Right(result, 1) = "," Then
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If

    get_address = result

End Function

Public Function area_address(r As range) As String

    Dim x As Double
    Dim result As String

    For x = 1 To r.Areas.count
        result = result + r.Areas.Item(x).address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False) + ","
    Next x

    If Right(result, 1) = "," Then
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If
    area_address = result
End Function

Public Function get_address_range(wks As Worksheet, r_ad As String) As String

'***Find the range***
Dim rs1 As range, rs2 As range

On Error Resume Next
Set rs1 = wks.range(r_ad).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       Set rs1 = Nothing
    End If

Set rs2 = wks.range(r_ad).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set rs2 = Nothing
    End If

'***Extract range address***
Dim ad1 As String, ad2 As String
Dim result As String

ad1 = rs1.address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)
ad2 = rs2.address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)

result = ad1 + "," + ad2

If Right(result, 1) = "," Then
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
End If

get_address_range = result

End Function

'******SUPPORTING FUNCTION*******
'*********For DetectSizeX_v6*****
Public Function get_col_name(ByVal address As String, max_min As Boolean)

'****Extract column name from address + cleaning address****
'address = "D2: D7 , G8, B2: B9 , F7: F9 , C2: C10 , E2: E13 , B13: D13"
'Note: if get_col_name return string "0", it means an error
address = EXTEXT(address)
address = Replace(address, ",", " ")
address = Replace(address, ":", " ")
address = EXNONBLANK(address)

'***Split address into individual string***
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(address, " ")

'***Convert column names into index***
    Dim x As Double
    Dim arr_size As Double
    Dim arr_num() As Double

    arr_size = UBound(arr)
    ReDim arr_num(0 To arr_size)

    For x = 0 To arr_size
        arr_num(x) = col_num(arr(x))
    Next x

'***Extract the max and the min col name/char***
    Dim temp_num As Double
    Dim max_char As String
    Dim min_char As String

        '***Max:
        temp_num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(arr_num)
        For x = 0 To arr_size
            If arr_num(x) = temp_num Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        max_char = arr(x)

        '***Min:
        temp_num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(arr_num)
        For x = 0 To arr_size
            If arr_num(x) = temp_num Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        min_char = arr(x)

'***Return value***
If max_min Then
    get_col_name = max_char
Else
    get_col_name = min_char
End If

End Function

Public Function get_row(ByRef address As String, max_min As Boolean)

Dim x As Double
Dim max_ad As String, min_ad As String
Dim max_row As Double, min_row As Double

For x = Len(address) To 1 Step -1
    If Mid(address, x, 1) = "," Then
        max_ad = Right(address, Len(address) - x)
        Exit For
    End If
Next x

For x = 1 To Len(address)
    If Mid(address, x, 1) = "," Then
        min_ad = Left(address, x - 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next x

max_ad = EXNONBLANK(EXNUM(max_ad))
min_ad = EXNONBLANK(EXNUM(min_ad))

'***get_max_min

Dim arr() As String
Dim arr_val() As Double
Dim arr_size As Double

arr = Split(max_ad + " " + min_ad, " ")
arr_size = UBound(arr, 1)
ReDim arr_val(0 To arr_size)

For x = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
    arr_val(x) = Val(arr(x))
Next x

max_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(arr_val)
min_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(arr_val)

If max_min Then
    get_row = max_row
Else
    get_row = min_row
End If

End Function
Public Function EXTEXT(TextIn As String, _
                Optional separator As String = " ") As String

Dim x As Double 'for long text
Dim result As String

    For x = 1 To Len(TextIn)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(TextIn, x, 1)) Then
                result = result + separator
            Else
                result = result + Mid(TextIn, x, 1) + separator
            End If
    Next x

If Len(result) >= 1 And Right(result, 1) = separator Then
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
End If

EXTEXT = result
End Function
Public Function EXNUM(TextIn As String, _
                Optional separator As String = " ") As String

Dim x As Double
Dim result As String

    For x = 1 To Len(TextIn)
            If Not IsNumeric(Mid(TextIn, x, 1)) Then
                result = result + separator
            Else
                result = result + Mid(TextIn, x, 1)
            End If
    Next x

    If Len(result) >= 1 And Right(result, 1) = separator Then
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If

EXNUM = result
End Function

'***Convert col_name to col_number
Public Function col_num(col_name As String)
    col_num = range(col_name & 1).Column
End Function
'***End Convert col_name to col_number


Function EXNONBLANK(str As String) As String
Do While InStr(str, "  ") > 0
    str = Replace$(str, "  ", " ")
Loop
EXNONBLANK = trim$(str)
End Function
'====================================
'**********End Detectsize V6*********
'====================================
```

Comment: instead of Excel function available as `worksheetfunction.trim()` use simple vba function `Trim()`. if not working you should show us your code...

Comment: btw, `worksheetfunction.trim()` working ok. form me even for a string with 2k characters in it

Comment: Hi @KazJaw, if I am not wrong, vba function `trim` only remove leading and trailing space, not the in-between space like `worksheetfuction.trim()` does. I'll post my code right away.

Comment: yes, you are right with this... so, my first idea is then wrong but still `worksheetfunction.trim()` doesn't have limitation on my computer with Excel 2010.

Comment: I also use Excel 2010. If that the case, then there could be mistake in my code.

Comment: can you short exaple of string before `EXNUM function`, after it and what you expect in fact?

Comment: before EXNUM, the string is like : "A1, B2:T3, D15:Z27,....". What I want to get is the row number of the first and the last range. I know I can get this through Areas collection but I also want to get the left-most and right-most column so I need this string.

Comment: one note, the length was not 1000 but 39000, my bad. It returned error when the string was around 39000 chars.

Comment: Excel cell length is limited to 32767 chars, so this is probably the cause of the error you received

Comment: oh god... thank you @user3964075. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: So you are gathering the used range of the sheet (by area), stripping out non-numerics, then trimming the result? Why are you doing this, and what is your full code - I think it could be improved from what you are working with.

Comment: @brettdj : just posted my code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction`'s are limited by the same constraints as a worksheet. For Strings in Cells that's 32767 characters (as commented by user3964075).

Your best option is to roll your own Trim function, something like this

```
Function MyTrim(s As String) As String
    Do While InStr(s, "  ") > 0
        s = Replace$(s, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    MyTrim = Trim$(s)
End Function
```

Performance wise this is actually slightly faster (10%) than `WorksheetFunction.Trim` (tested on strings of 30,000 char)

Comment: 32kb limit?  *Lame.*  I guess that explains why I'm getting ***`Unable to get the Trim property of the WorksheetFunction class`*** on my **42,000,000** character string.  :-(